# Fastest way to replace string in first row of huge file in linux command line?

Tags: linux, file, text-processing

I have a huge plain text file (~500Gb) on linux machine. I want the replace some string in header line (the first row of the file), but all the method I known seems to be slow and low efficiency.

example file:

```
foo apple cat
1    2    2
2    3    4
3    4    6
...
```

expected file output:

```
bar apple cat
1    2    2
2    3    4
3    4    6
...
```

---

**sed**:

```
sed -i '1s/foo/bar/g' file
```

`-i` can change the file in place, but this command generate a tmp file on disk and use the tmp file to replace the original one. The io waste time.

---

**vim**:

```
ex -c '1s/foo/bar/g' -c 'wq' file
```

vim doesn't generate a tmp file, but this tool load the whole file in to memory, which waste a lot of time either.

---

Is there a better solution that only read the first row in to memory and write it back to the original file? I known that linux `head` command can extract the first column very fast.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: This can only be done if `foo` and `bar` are the same length (in bytes). Otherwise, rewriting the entire file is your only option (although it can be done in-place if the tool is smart enough).

Comment: @cyrus I had add the example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reorder lines near the beginning of a huge text file (>20G)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987897/reorder-lines-near-the-beginning-of-a-huge-text-file-20g)

Comment: @Thomas The new string and the old differs in length. It seems rewriting the file is the only solution, but I still wonder which command is the fastest way to do so.

Comment: @ChangYe, could you please do let me know if you tried my awk solution, just curios to know about how it goes?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following awk command and let me know if this helps you, I couldn't test it as I don't have a huge size file like 500 GB. For sure it shouldn't create any temp file in backend as it is not using inplace substitution on Input_file.

```
awk 'FNR==1{$1="bar";print;next} 1' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you @RavinderSingh13. This command can deal with this problem, but there isn't any improvement  of speed. As Thomas suggested, there may not be a better way to do so, unless I keep the sting length unchanged.